How can the timeout duration for API Gateway be extended when interfacing with Lambda?
I'm currently facing a challenge with the integration between API Gateway and Lambda. Specifically, when API Gateway triggers the Lambda function, the process takes about 40-50 seconds to complete. However, I need this process to run longer, ideally around 2-3 minutes. So I want API Gateway to wait till Lambda responds with an answer.
I'm wondering if there's a way to adjust the timeout duration of API Gateway to accommodate this longer processing time. Additionally, I'm open to exploring alternative approaches to resolve this issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

API gateway is not a suitable integration because the timeout limit it has (30 secs I think) is a strict upper limit. If you want a longer timeout you can use an Application Load Balancer (but that has additional costs). Without knowing what your specific workflow is I can't really say anything else.

An HTTP request should not take more than a few seconds to process, ideally <200ms. If you need something longer running, you want a background job with an HTTP interface to it. The flow would be to create the background job with an HTTP request, which completes immediately. You can then check on the status of your background job periodically with a quick HTTP request, and get its result when it's done.
